# Gradle + TestNG: setting up classes to run

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, testng

I am creating a Gradle project to be used in conjunction with TestNG. So far, I am running the TestNG file, structured in this form, to run tests:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Default Suite">
    <test name="Test">
        <classes>
            <class name="package1.class1"></class>
            <class name="package2.class2"></class>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

What I'd like to do is to have the Gradle build file do the same thing as what I am currently doing when I run this testng.xml file (i.e. run class 1's test suite, and then class 2's suite). After doing a little searching, my build.gradle file currently looks like this:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    // add the dependencies as needed
    testCompile group: 'org.testng', name: 'testng', version:'6.9.10'
    testCompile fileTree('lib')
}

test {

    useTestNG() {

        // Run the test suite textng.xml, which is in the same directory.
        suites 'testng.xml';

        include '**/*package1.class1.*'
        include '**/*package2.class2.*'
    }
}
```

...and my settings.gradle file like this:

```
include 'shared'
include 'api'
include 'services:webservice'

rootProject.name = 'Project1'
```

When I run with this configuration, however, the tests do not run as expected. What am I missing from this code?

**EDIT**: After doing some more digging, I decided to try running TestNG directly from Gradle, creating a new testng.xml file:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {

    // Add any necessary dependencies.
    testCompile group: 'org.testng', name: 'testng', version:'6.9.10'
    testCompile fileTree('lib')

    compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-api', version: '2.5'
    compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-core', version: '2.5'
}



task runTests(type: JavaExec, dependsOn: 'classes') {

    classpath = files("${projectDir}/src", project.sourceSets.main.compileClasspath,
                project.sourceSets.test.compileClasspath,
                project.sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath,
                project.sourceSets.test.runtimeClasspath)

    main = 'org.testng.TestNG'

    args = ["-parallel",  "methods", "-threadcount", "1", "-d", "./build/test-output", "testng.xml"]
}
```

I think both approaches could potentially go somewhere, except that, even though I've included the location of my source directory, I'm still getting this error:

```
Cannot find class in classpath: package1.class1
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you should put your include/exclude conditions directly to testng.xml file.